# spliting Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

It is well known that vanishing of Riemann curvature tensor is equivalent to the existance of coordinate system where Christoffel Symbols are zero.
That is to say:

$R^a_{bcd}=0 \iff \exists\text{ Coord Sys }(x): \Gamma^i_{jk}(x)=0$

Is it a way to state a similar about a-th component of this tensor? That is:
$R^i_{bcd}=0 \iff \exists\text{ Coord Sys }(x): \Gamma^i_{jk}(x)=0$,

for any i ?

For example:

$R^1_{bcd}=0 \iff \exists\text{ Coord Sys }(x): \Gamma^1_{jk}(x)=0$,

but the rest are unrestricted.

Since we have:

$R^i_{jkl}=\frac{\partial \Gamma^i_{jl}}{\partial x^k}-\frac{\partial \Gamma^i_{jk}}{\partial x^l}+\Gamma^s_{jl}\Gamma^i_{ks}-\Gamma^s_{jk}\Gamma^i_{ls}$,

the implication that $R^i_{bcd}=0$ when $\Gamma^i_{jk}=0$ is trivial.
How can I prove (or disprove) an implication in the oposite way.

I will be gratefull for any suggestions!

PS. What is the proper mathematical symbol to express: "a coordinate system with coordinates $(x^1...x^n)$"? I don't like the way I've done it here.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense as written: $R^a{}_{bcd}$ denotes the full curvature tensor, and whether all of the components of curvature vanish does not depend on a choice of coordinates or frame. But simply by writing $R^1{}_{bcd}$ means having chosen coordinates (or some frame, anyway), and this quantity might vanish for some choices of frame and not others. One *could* patch this issue by changing the hypothesis to the (local or global) existence of a nonvanishing $1$-form $\alpha$ such that $\alpha_a R^a{}_{bcd} = 0$.

Comment: A valid point, thank you. However, I think that it does not solve my problem, since Christoffel symbols are not tensors. Therefore, the following statement seems to be false:
$\alpha_a R^a_{bcd}=0 \iff \alpha_a \Gamma^a_{jk}=0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly false. For example, for a flat metric in polar coordinates, not all Christoffel symbols are zero, but the curvature is zero. Thus, we can choose an $\alpha_a$ for which the implication $\Rightarrow$ vanishes.

Comment: You are right again. However my statement is not corect. What I mean is:$$\alpha_a R^a_{bcd}=0 \iff \exists\text{ Coord Sys }(x): \alpha_a\Gamma^a_{jk}(x)=0$$This can be seen as a question if there is possible to "count" flat directions and curved ones based on riemann tensor. For example if a quater of the tensor vashish (no matter which elements exacly) we can postulate that there is one flat direction and 3 curved (in 4 dimensional space).

Comment: I don't have much intuition, I would have to play around with some examples even to guess whether that was true or not. One can make good sense of "counting flat directions" in invariant terms, too, i.e., without referring to any coordinate system at all. For example, for a fixed point $p$, we can ask for the maximum dimension of the subspaces $E$ for which $R^a{}_{bcd} X^c = 0$ for all $X \in E$---where the metric is locally flat, this maximum is $\dim M$. For the round metric on the sphere this maximum is $0$.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you provide any reference to this topic? I have tried google but without any interesting results. For example, a derivation of the equation $R^a_{bcd}X^c=0$ will be helpful. If I understand correctly this could be solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: I was just pointing out that one *could* define such a thing and in particular do so invariantly. I don't know any references offhand, but I know this has been studied (I only know anything about the projective and conformal versions of that condition).